# What is the time unit for pm2 watch_delay option?

Tags: node.js, pm2

The pm2 [docs](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/) say there is an option to set a `watch-delay` in a configuration file like this:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    script: "app.js",
    watch: ["server", "client"],
    // Delay between restart
    watch_delay: 1000,
    ignore_watch : ["node_modules", "client/img"],
  }]
}
```

But it does not mention the time unit for the `watch_delay` option. Is it `ms`? Does anyone know what the time unit is? If it is `ms`, is there anywhere in the docs that this can be confirmed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`watch_delay` value time unit is millisecond.

To be more specific, the `pm2 --help` says tha you can add `--watch-delay 4` or `--watch-delay 4000` for a delay of 4 s.